# Is there a way to initialize a member object of a class within the constructors code instead of the initializer list?

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, member

Consider I want to wrap some library code inside an object. That library needs to be set up and initialized by calling some function inside the constructor of that wrapper class.

The librarie's "objects" then diverge into creating more, different "objects" that the wrapper class wraps in form of yet another wrapper object that should be a plain member of that class.

But as far as I see it, members of classes can only be initialized or created by calling their constructor in the initalizer list of the constructor. The execution of these bits of code preceed the constructor of the actual class that does the initialization of the library and its environment, making it impossible for me to actually initialize that member object as a member and instead force me to initialize it as a pointer to the 2nd wrapper, because its constructor must be called manually within the first constructor's code.

Example:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        if(!wrapped_library_init()) {
            exit(CRITICAL_ERROR);
        }
        ptr_to_some_library_metadata *a = library_function(); /*Needs to
        be called after wrapped_library_init() or needs a pointer to some
        wrapped object created inside this constructor */
        //initialize b
    }
private:
    B b; //Wants to be a member but can not
};

class B {
    B(ptr_to_some_library_metadata *a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Member objects can only be constructed in the member initializer list. There are a few techniques which can be used to make it possible to initialize an object, though:

1. Use a helper [lambda] function doing the necessary extra work before return a suitable object. For example:

   ```
   A()
         : B([]{
             if (!wrapped_library_init()) {
                 exit(CRITICAL_ERROR);
             }
             return library_function();
         }()) {
   }
   ```
2. You can delay construction by using a `union` with just the appropriate member. When using this technique the member needs to be explicitly destructed, for example:

   ```
   class A {
       union Bu { B b };
       Bu b;
   public:
       A() {
           if (!wrapped_library_init()) {
               exit(CRITICAL_ERROR);
           }
           new(&b.b) B(library_function());
       }
       ~A() {
           b.b.~B();
       }
       // ...
   };
   ```

I'd personally use the first approach. However, there are cases when using a `union` to delay construction is helpful.

Comment: For case 2, `std::optional` instead of the union to have free rule of 5/3/0 (else creating a class "`delayed_construct<T>`" to avoid the overhead of `optional`).

Comment: @Jarod42: I'd not be willing to pay for `std::optional`s need to indicate whether it is set or not. I do agree, however, that the delayed construction can reasonably be factored into a class template. On the other hand, my experience is that wrapper classes become resource managers anyway as they typically need special initialization as well as destruction.

Comment: My primary point was to underline that there is not just the destructor to implement, but also the --copy--/assignment/move. As I found it was not clear in your post (might be included in `//...`). So lazy people can pay the overhead :-)

Answer (score 1):

Initializer lists are there to use another constructor than the default constructor.

But nothing impedes you for creating a custom function that will initialize `b`:

```
class A {
public:
    A():b(init()) {
    }
private:
    B b; //Wants to be a member but can not

    static B init()
    {
        if(!wrapped_library_init()) {
            exit(CRITICAL_ERROR);
        }
        ptr_to_some_library_metadata *a = library_function(); /*Needs to
        be called after wrapped_library_init() or needs a pointer to some
        wrapped object created inside this constructor */

        return B(a);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your library inside a class:

```
class LibraryWrapper
{
public:
    LibraryWrapper()
    {
        if(!wrapped_library_init()) {
            exit(CRITICAL_ERROR);
        }
        lib_data.reset(library_function()); /*Needs to
        be called after wrapped_library_init() or needs a pointer to some
        wrapped object created inside this constructor */
    }
    //~LibraryWrapper() {/**/}
    //LibraryWrapper(const LibraryWrapper&) {/**/}            // =delete; ?
    //LibraryWrapper& operator=(const LibraryWrapper&) {/**/} // =delete; ?

//private: // and appropriate interface to hide internal
    std::unique_ptr<ptr_to_some_library_metadata, CustomDeleter> lib_data;
};

class B {
public:
    explicit B(ptr_to_some_library_metadata *a);
    // ...
};
```

And use extra member or inheritance:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : b(lib.lib_data.get()) {}
private:
    LibraryWrapper lib; // placed before B
    B b;
};
```